# jeditable not working

Tags: jeditable

I did not make any changes on the code. I dont receive any errors but its not working.
I must be missing something very very simple here. Any suggestion appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all I see in your HTML is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

you need to include jeditable javascript files too. jeditable is not included in jQuery.
download both jeditable and jquery on your local server. best not use remote resources.

**[edit]**

The div you want to make editable is not available yet since it's coming from AJAX.
Add the jeditable code in `success: function(data) {`

Comment: Hi, it is included. Just not at the top.

Comment: I placed jeditable code where you told me to but its still not updating.

Comment: Its not working because I refresh that area every 5 seconds. Thank you so much!

Comment: For decreased latency, increased parallelism, and improved caching, keep jquery hosted remotely. http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/